# How to configure `less` to print starting from the top of terminal window?

Tags: less

I recently switched from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 and although they seem to have the same version of `less`, 458, I get different behavior.

In my new system, if a file has fewer lines than the terminal then `less` shows it in the bottom of the terminal window, like this:

```
                          <-
                          <- empty space, not part of file
                          <-
file starts here
  ...
last line of the file
(END) <- symbol inserted by LESS
```

In my experience with other systems I would get the following behavior instead:

```
file starts here
  ...
last line of the file
(END) <- symbol inserted by LESS
                          <-
                          <- empty space
                          <-
```

This is a minor issue but nonetheless important. 
The problem with the new behavior is that I can't tell from the output whether the file actually starts with empty lines or it's just the way `less` outputs it because it's too short for the terminal window.

Comment: which terminal emulation are you using? try "echo $TERM". if using "xterm", this should work as you want. (export TERM=xterm)

Comment: I'm using `xterm-256color`. The export did not work but the accepted answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-c` option will force `less` to start from the top of the screen. You can apply it by default by adding it to the `LESS` environment variable:

```
LESS="${LESS:+$LESS }-c"
export LESS
```

This will take whatever is currently in `LESS`, if anything, and add `-c` to it, with a space if necessary.

Comment: Why `${VAR+...}` and not the more canonical `${VAR:+...}`?

Comment: @Otheus I'm not sure what you mean by "more canonical", but `:+` is indeed more appropriate in this case, thanks!

Comment: re "Canonical", strike that. I've simply never seen it before. I think this is like the 4th time one of your answers has positively stunned me.